# imagettftext not working

Tags: php, debian, text, gd

I've tried to write text in an image just for testing purposes because my Zabbix install is not writing text in the graphs. I've copied the code bellow from the php.net website (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php)

```
<?php
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf'; 

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Describe your problem. What isn't working?

Comment: I've figure out what was the problem here. Permissions to access the truetype file. PHP could not access the file so it couldn't write.

I was not seeing the problem because I was not running with E_ALL. Now everything is running smoothly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figure out what was the problem here. Permissions to access the truetype file. PHP could not access the file so it couldn't write.

I was not seeing the problem because I was not running with E_ALL. Now everything is running smoothly

Answer (score 2):

My issue was a wrong offset. The image was showing nothing, no text, no errors in the source code, just a blank file. The paths were correct. I thought there was an error in the ttf font but turns out it was just wrong positioning.

Here's what helped me to see a bit of the text:

```
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 20, 20, $fg, $font, $text);
```

This shows a bit of text on the top right.

Full working code:

```
    putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . dirname(__FILE__));
    $font = 'arial'; // located next to the script
    imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 20, 20, $fg, $font, $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a GD function and you will need php-gd installed with gettext & ttf support.

-$

Comment: GD is bundled with PHP now. The other requirement is the [FreeType](http://www.freetype.org/) library

Comment: I knew about that. It was ok. I could draw, and I could write without truetype. The problem was accessing the font file.