# imagettftext function not working in php

Tags: php, captcha, imagettftext

I have the following code for my captcha. The lines in the image are generated but the 4 digit number is not displayed. I assume there is some problem in

**imagettftext($image,$font_size,0,15,30,$text_color,'font.TTF',$text);**

function of code. I tried setting the path to the font file using $_server['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; yet didn't work.

here's the code:

```
        <?php
    session_start();
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

    $text= $_SESSION['secure'];

    $font_size =30;
    $image_width= 110;
    $image_height=40;

    $image=imagecreate($image_width,$image_height);
    imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);


    for($x=1; $x<=30; $x++){
        $x1 = rand(1,100);
        $x2 = rand(1,100);
        $y1 = rand(1,100);
        $y2 = rand(1,100);
    imageline($image, $x1, $x2, $y1, $y2, $text_color);
    }

    imagettftext($image,$font_size,0,15,30,$text_color,'font.TTF',$text);
    imagejpeg($image);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code Perfectly working in my pc

Remember font path should be correct.

output- [image]

```
<?php

// Set the content-type
header('Content-type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: I'm sorry , i didn't understand what you are actually trying to say?

Comment: see this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496809/why-isnt-the-php-imagettftext-function-working-in-this-case

Comment: see both of url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034698/imagettftext-not-working

Comment: i did the required changes but still the same issue >> pingcampus.com/mysql/generate.php

Comment: see this url again http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/881252-imagettftext-function-not-working

Comment: It still doesnt shows up anything www.pingcampus.com/mysql/123.php 

Thats your code here

Comment: @user1460822 That's strange, I just run Abid's code on localhost and it shows the text correctly.

Comment: @stano thats what the problem is , i can easily run my code as well on my localhost, but it's not working on the hosting. I approached the support team of my hosting and they say that it is a scripting issue which we won't be able to help with

Comment: @user1460822 Surely you copied the arial.ttf from C:/Windows/Fonts/ to the script directory? Also you can check that uppercase in "font.TTF". If the font file is not found, that function imagettftext() prints nothing.

Comment: @stano yes i copied the font file from : C:/windows/fonts/ and i also have checked the uppercase

Comment: Over the internet i read about something called "GD" what is that?

Comment: "Graphic Device"... you can also try to add at the beginning of the script the command: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` - if you get something like "image cannot be displayed contains errors", then there is some notice at the beginning of the file - save it and see the message in text editor.

Comment: Thought it to change the order like this: `session_start(); $text= $_SESSION['secure']; die($text); header('Content-type: image/jpeg');` ...etc

Comment: @stano the support sucks on my hosting, all they returned me with is:

20120805T072136: pingcampus.com/mysql/generate.php 
PHP Warning: session_start(): open(/var/php_sessions/sess_721f4c54d74002e3048d65626a8e7dfe, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /hermes/bosweb/web054/b548/ipg.pingcampuscom/mysql/generate.php on line 2

Comment: @user1460822 hi, found [this advice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#108901), or [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#94783), or [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#88588) - only searched for the **Warning** word. Dunno if it can help you.